# Carbon date difference in minutes, hours, days, etc

Tags: php, php-carbon

I am using the `Carbon` Date library.

I want the difference between two dates which outputs directly as below:

1. If the difference is in minutes, then it should show something like `26 Minutes`
2. If the difference in hours, then it should show something like `4 hours 3 Minutes`
3. If the difference is in days, hours, minutes then it should show something like `2 Days 9 Hours 7 Minutes`
4. If the difference is in days & minutes, then it should show something like `3 Days 10 Minutes` and NOT `3 Days 0 Hours 10 Minutes`

I am having a solution where I check, `d`, `h`, `i` and set the data manually, also I don't want the solution as `0 Days 0 Hours 15 Minutes`.

The logic should be smart enough to omit the `0` ones.

So I searched under Carbon Documentation, but I didn't find one, I am not looking for the difference for Humans.

Hence I am looking if there is a Carbon Method which I have not discovered.

Thanks.

Comment: I am unaware of such functionality. Also, what is your desired output when one of the "middle" units is zero? For example, `2 Days 0 Hours 7 Minutes` or should it be `2 Days 7 Minutes`?

Comment: Okay, It should be, 2 Days 7 Minutes

Comment: I suggest you edit that into the question.